# How to check which users have used sudo, using grep?

Tags: command-line

Having root privileges: select from file `/etc/passwd` lines that have `/bin/bash`, get user names (field1), and find out from log file `/var/log/auth.log` if they used `sudo`. I've used `grep` and `cut` to find the names of users, but i can't figure out how to check if they used sudo. How to `grep` usernames and sudo? Or maybe I need to use another command?

Comment: What did you try so far, where are you stuck ?

Comment: First you need to use `grep` with "bash" on passwd then pipe to `cut` to extract the names, then you can use `for` loop with `grep` as argument or pipe `cut` to `while read name; do` and then do `grep "$name"` on log file. This looks like assignments so you need to do this yourself, or at least try and then ask if you have problems.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it from the other direction: Get all users that have recently used `sudo` and list the ones that have `bash` as their login shell:

```
sed -nE 's/.*[0-9] ([^ ]+) sudo:.*/\1/p' </var/log/auth.log | sort -u |
while read user; do
    getent passwd "$user" |
    awk -F ':' '$NF == "/bin/bash" { print $1 }'
done
```

The `sed` expression extracts the usernames of users that have used `sudo`, `sort -u` sorts these and removes duplicates, and the loop tests whether these remaining users have `/bin/bash` set as their login shell.  If they have, the username is printed.

It makes sense to do it in this order if the `auth.log` file is really big and you don't want to parse it once for each `bash` user.  Instead we run `getent` once for each user in the logfile. But we can improve on that...

In the proposed order:

```
getent passwd |
awk -F ':' '$NF == "/bin/bash" { printf("s/.*[0-9] (%s) sudo:.*/\\1/p\n", $1) }' |
sed -nE -f - /var/log/auth.log | sort -u
```

Here, the `awk` script creates a `sed` script.  On my Ubuntu test machine, this script will look like

```
s/.*[0-9] (root) sudo:.*/\1/p
s/.*[0-9] (ubuntu) sudo:.*/\1/p
s/.*[0-9] (myself) sudo:.*/\1/p
s/.*[0-9] (otheruser) sudo:.*/\1/p
```

This `sed` script is then run against the `auth.log` logfile and will output the names of `bash`-using users that have recently used `sudo`. The result is sorted and duplicates are removed.

Here, we don't parse the logfile more than once, and additionally we don't need more than a single call to `getent`.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through each user in `/etc/passwd` with a shell of `/bin/bash`, then `grep` for the user in `/var/log/auth.log`, then uses `awk` to check if the fifth field is 'sudo:' and the sixth is the name of the user, `sort` and `uniq` are then used to return a list of users who have used `sudo` (who also have a shell of `/bin/bash` in `/etc/passwd`:

```
for user in $(awk -F: '$7 == "/bin/bash"{print $1}' /etc/passwd);do 
  grep "$user" /var/log/auth.log|\
  awk -v user="$user" '$5 == "sudo:" && $6 == user {print user}'
done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: `grep` on `/etc/passwd` doesn't work for AD users. `getent passwd` will get all users. Just in case ...

Comment: grep on /etc/passwd wont work for any user that isn't in /etc/passwd, getent would indeed be a better source but that's not what the OP asked for. There's not really any need to look up the user for anywhere, you could just pull a list of users from the auth.log

Comment: true, this would actually be the best thing ;-)

Comment: So just this: `sudo awk -v user="$user" '$5 == "sudo:" { print $6 }' /var/log/auth.log | sort -u` and then find out if these use `/bin/bash` for whatever reason this is important.